# -webkit-box-reflect in firefox and IE - CSS

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome, webkit

I'm still new to Reflections in CSS and so on, so having some issue with this. For the home page I have been told I need to reflect text and then an image (as well as a complicated shadow behind but that's on my to-do list).

For chrome/safari (webkit) I have got

> -webkit-box-reflect: below 0px -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(transparent), color-stop(70%, transparent), to(rgba(255,255,255,0.2)));

Looks very nice... However... obviously it only works with chrome/safari. How would I go about getting the same effect in Internet explorer (7/8/9 if possible) and Firefox?

Thanks,
Nicholas Carter

Answer (score 4):

You should use the `-moz-element` attribute for Firefox.

For reflection it will be:

```
#reflection {
  /* It's a copy of the original element... */
  background: -moz-element(#reflected-element)
              bottom left no-repeat;

  /* ... turned upside down ... */
  -moz-transform: scaleY(-1);

  /* ... with a gradual fade-out effect towards the bottom. */
  mask: url(#reflection-mask);
}
```

[What is -moz-element?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/element?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2F-moz-element)

[Reference](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/08/mozelement/)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can provide a jQuery fallback with [this plugin](http://www.digitalia.be/software/reflectionjs-for-jquery).

This tutorial also talks about [cross-browser reflection](http://blog.gface.com/2012/02/22/crossbrowser-css3-reflections/).

---

To target browsers not supporting reflections you can use [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com).

This build: http://modernizr.com/download/#-cssreflections-cssclasses-testprop-testallprops-domprefixes will add a `no-cssreflections` class to your page `<html>` tag.

Then, you can add a specific CSS rule:

```
.no-cssreflections #element-id {
    /* custom CSS rule */
}
```

or via JavaScript:

```
if(!Modernizr.cssreflections){
    /* run plugin or whatever */
}
```